# Type of Flu Shot for Person in Late 30s - Which Standard Dose Provides Most Protection?

Tags: influenza

**Updated Question**

Of all the standard dose vaccines, which one is most strongest?

Flu shot doesn't guarantee against flu, but it is a layer of defense.

According to  this link there is Afluria, Fluarix, FluLavel, Fluzone. How are they different, which one should I ask for?

[Influenza Vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/66/rr/rr6602a1.htm#T1_down)

For 2015 to 2016 I received FLUARIX QUAD 2015-2015 SYRINGE in Dec 2015

For 2016 to 2017 I received AFLURIA 2016-2017 SYRINGE in Oct 2016

Comment: Flu shots have nothing to do with sneezing. They prevent flu. That's all.

Comment: As Carey said, it's not the vaccine;  your sneezing could be seasonal allergies or a myriad of other things. Totally unrelated. You can't get the flu from the flu vaccine.  Get whatever vaccine that is available.

Comment: Also, flu vaccines are highly different from year to year. Basically (as I understand it) they are versions of whichever flu variant the health professionals think are going to be the most prevalent each season.

Comment: @JohnP Furthermore, the flu virus itself is mutating a lot, meaning there is need for multiple vaccinations and new vaccines. In Germany, vaccination against the flu is not recommended for the majority of patients because it would have to be renewed every year to be effective. It is encouraged very much for the elderly though because a flu could be lethal for an already strained immune system.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Vaccinating every year is exactly what is recommended in the US for everyone. Considering how inexpensive the flu vaccine is and how dreadfully ill it can make even a young, healthy person, skipping it seems "penny wise, pound foolish."

Comment: That’s interesting to learn. In Germany, there Is a general aversion towards taking any medication at all (try to convince parents that their child is desperately in need of antibiotics) and I suspect this is just another aspect of that mentality. It is healthy in some ways (you do not need antibiotics when you have a common cold, although a Japanese doctor I know supports this idea) but really unhealthy in other ways (if you have developed a serious cause of pneumonia).

Comment: Rhonda, If I were going to answer your question, my answer would consist largely of quotes from the link you provided. I don't think the particular brand matters. What matters is the formulation, which the link you provided explains in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pharmacist or doctor should be able to decide which one is the best fit for you. Factors that are considered in recommendations include age, allergies (egg or mercury), and your medical history specifically if you are on a continuous steroid therapy or if you are pregnant or breastfeeding.

The medication that you received last year "AFLURIA" is not a Quadrivalent vaccine which means it only has the protection of 3 strains of the flu instead of 4. As mentioned in the comments, the strains selected is based on studies by health professionals to figure out the prevalence of a strain in a specific year. To get the extra protection ask for a quadrivalent vaccine and let the healthcare professional make the decision based on what he/she has available and your history. I have not found a study to compare the efficacy of the different quadrivalent vaccines and I do not think there will be one.

I would cite sources for what I said above, but this is all based on my experience as a healthcare professional. If you need additional information CDC website is your best source.

[edit] also, the CDC provide a tool to figure out which vaccines you need at your age and sometimes provide a specific recommendation. Give it a try: https://www2a.cdc.gov/nip/adultimmsched/

Comment: Thank you for adding the CDC link. Without it I would have had to downvote your answer. The problem with citing professional experience here is that we have no way of verifying it. Anybody can claim to be a brain surgeon, after all, and if they talk a good game, who's going to be the wiser?

Comment: @CareyGregory I tried my best, this question and many other questions on this site cannot be addressed without clinical experience. People think they can "shop" for healthcare. But really the decision for selecting a product will be a decision that the vaccine administrator will make. I strongly advise talking to whoever is giving the vaccine and seek their opinion instead of trying to find a recommendation online. Leave it to the professionals. If you do not believe in the one that you go to, seek another one that meets your expectations.